# Java Listener for data sent from my mobile to a java application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So here' my basic idea:

I have an android application which will read a barcode and generate an equivalent string. That string will be sent to my PC.

I have a java GUI application which has a `TextField` which will be automatically filled with that string whenever it is sent from my mobile to my PC.

So how do I do this and what will I require.

Comment: what you want to do as you already have an android app

Comment: I want to transfer data from my mobile to my java program since I am creating a java program.

Comment: which java program and where on mobile or pc

Comment: I have the java program on my pc. My idea is like i would like to scan a barcode and send the data to my java program. I am creating java software for supermarket automation. The person will scan the item barcode with their phone and send it to my java prgram which will give details about the item.

Comment: so wat you want to know specific?

Comment: what will i require in my java program? like some kind of a listener function etc??

Comment: what for if you need to communicate between devices pc and mobile there need to have connectivity so then listener will come in play

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Create a web application to receive input from the phone.  The location of this application at run time is not important; you will only need to know the URL to access it.
2. Post the information from your phone to the web application using an HTTP Post Request.
3. there is no next step.